# How to use ConnectionListner and/or ChannelListner for logging failure/success of message delivery in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am trying to log any information or exception that occurs during message sending in RabbitMQ, for that I tried to add ConnectionListener on the existing connection factory.

```
    kRabbitTemplate.getConnectionFactory().addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Connection connection) {
            System.out.println("Connection Created");
        }

        @Override
        public void onShutDown(ShutdownSignalException signal) {
            System.out.println("Connection Shutdown "+signal.getMessage());
        }

    });
    kRabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, routingkey, empDTO);
```

To test the exception scenario, I unbind and even deleted the queue from RabbitMQ console. But I did not get any exception or any shutdown method call.

Although, When I stopped RabbitMQ service, I got

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

But this exception is not from the listener I added.

I want to know

1. Why I did not get any exception or call from shutdown method
2. How can I use ConnectionListner and/or ChannelListner for logging failure/success of message delivery.
3. Can we use the AMQP appender, if yes how can we do that? (any example / tutorial)
4. What are the other approaches to ensure the message is sent?

Note: I do not want to use the publisher confirm the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Connection Refused` is not a `ShutdownSignalException` - the connection was never established because the broker is not present on the server/port.

You can't use the listeners to confirm delivery or return of individual messages; use publisher confirms and returns for that.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#publishing-is-async

See the documentation for how to use the appenders.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#logging

**EDIT**

To get notified of failures to connect, you currently need to use other techniques, depending on whether you are sending or receiving.

Here is an example that shows how:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So66882099Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So66882099Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So66882099Application.class, args);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    void listen(String in) {

    }

    // consumer side listeners for no connection

    @EventListener
    void consumerFailed(ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent event) {
        log.error(event + " via event listener");
        if (event.getThrowable() instanceof AmqpConnectException) {
            log.error("Broker down?");
        }
    }

    // or

    @Bean
    ApplicationListener<ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent> eventListener() {
        return event -> log.error(event + " via application listener");
    }

    // producer side - use a RetryListener

    @Bean
    RabbitTemplate template(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(cf);
        RetryTemplate retry = new RetryTemplate();
        // configure retries here as needed
        retry.registerListener(new RetryListener() {

            @Override
            public <T, E extends Throwable> boolean open(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback,
                    Throwable throwable) {

                log.error("Send failed " + throwable.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public <T, E extends Throwable> void close(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback,
                    Throwable throwable) {
            }

        });
        rabbitTemplate.setRetryTemplate(retry);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            try {
                template.convertAndSend("foo", "bar");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: On adding ConnectionListner/ChannelListner, we are getting calls for onCreate when connection/channel is created,
We added logging in ConnectionListner/ChannelListner's onShutDown method as well to check when the connection/channel are closed.
So by stopping rabbitMQ service, we tried to simulate the scenario of closing the RabbitMQ connection/channel, but it didn't work
Can you please let us know in what scenarios this onShutDown method will be called and how we could simulate these scenarios?

Comment: I am trying to leverage the existing functionality of ConnectionListener and ChannelListener to log any failure scenarios related to connection/ channel closed. Can you please elaborate regarding the support of this in these classes?

Comment: There is nothing to elaborate; the connection listener is currently all about established connections; it is called when a connection is opened and again when that connection is closed normally (or a shutdown signal is received). It is not involved if there never was a connection. Nobody has asked for this before; I'll open a new feature issue; in the meantime, I will edit my answer to show how to use other listeners for this use case.

Comment: I added an example to show how to get connection failure notifications; I also opened a new feature request https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1315